# Cheetsheet in Angular2-hotkeys not working

Tags: angular, hotkeys, angular-hotkeys

I am trying angular2-hotkeys library to provide hotkey functionality to my application. I have used the official documentation provided at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-hotkeys as an example.

As per the documentation, by using

```
<hotkeys-cheatsheet></hotkeys-cheatsheet>
```

we can have cheetsheet functionality enabled in our application. However, I am not sure how to add the hotkey list to this cheetsheet.

Additionally, is there a way we can have hotkeys auto-registered to cheetsheet when they are added.

Any leads are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the hotkeys with the HotkeysService.  `<hotkeys-cheatsheet>` listens to the same `HotkeysService` and will list whatever hotkeys are registered there.